# Win 10 Not Detecting DVD Drivers

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, dvd

I am trying to connect my Memorex 3202-3223 Multi Format Dvd Recorder to my Windows 10 desktop, but drivers are not automatically installed.  If I go to device manager and attempt to auto-download the best drivers I get the message saying best drivers are automatically installed.  Looking under Device Manager, this DVD Recorder shows with a yellow exclamation point beside it under USB and does not show at all under DVD Drives (only Virtual Clone drive does).

Why is my computer not recognizing this burner?

[image: USB Images]

[image: DVD Images]

Comment: Usually you won't need any special drivers for DVD-RW's (practically NEVER). Have you confirmed the DVD drive isn't just dead?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - yes the drive works perfectly when connected to a Win 7 computer